# How to locate a material ui text from a data control

Tags: material-ui

[image]

I am using this control from Material ui for my paging. I will like to edit the text "Rows per page" and change it to something else. I have been looking for this and unable to find it. Where can I locate it please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The label can be customized by changing the property `labelRowsPerPage`, e.g.

```
<TablePagination labelRowsPerPage="Rows" <!-- Add other props --> />
```

See the documentation [here](https://material-ui.com/api/table-pagination/).